# How to fix "Fetch to Code Inspector failed" in GitHub?

Tags: git, debugging, github, github-app

Uninstalled **Code-Inspector(CI)** Code Analysis app from my github account, but it still keep pushing danger alert notification error everytime the page is refreshed or some tab is clicked. I have installed and Uninstalled this app from Github Marketplace multiple times even revoked its Authorization from the settings but keep getting this alert error notification -"**Fetch to Code Inspector failed**"

[Notification Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76Puu.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- On your Chrome browser, click the [extention icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rv6LQ.png) (near top right corner)
- Scroll down your extensions, you'll find a section with header **Access requested**
- In that section, you'll find **Code Inspector**
- You can give access to the extension or remove it from the chrome

This will solve your problem